# Transforming pandas dataframe : un pivot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following dataframe :

```
commune nuance_1    votes_1 nuance_2    votes_2 nuance_3    votes_3
A       X           12      Y           20      Z           5 
B       X           10      Y            5      
C       Z            7      X            2
```

and I would like to obtain after transformation :

```
commune nuance  votes
A       X       12
A       Y       20
A       Z        5
B       X       10
B       Y        5
C       Z        7
C       X        2
```

Is there a way to do this ( sort of un pivot ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) here:

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df,['nuance','votes'],'commune','j',sep='_')
       .dropna(how='all').sort_index(0).droplevel(1).reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

 commune nuance  votes
0       A      X   12.0
1       A      Y   20.0
2       A      Z    5.0
3       B      X   10.0
4       B      Y    5.0
5       C      Z    7.0
6       C      X    2.0
```

Comment: Hello anky, thank you for sharing nice command, I am getting an error like `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'` before droplevel command runs fine, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you. `df.droplevel` was introduced in version `0.24.0`, looks like the pandas version you are using is less than that. However one can use `(.....sort_index(0).reset_index(0).reset_index(drop=True))` as a workaround.